# how to remove empty array values using ternary operator

Tags: php

need your help ,how can remove empty array values using ternary operator in php this is my code

```
<?php

$explode_values = array();
if (isset($checkpointvalues[$checkpoint['id']]['description'])) {
    $explode_values =  explode(",",@$checkpointvalues[$checkpoint['id']]['description']);
}
$a = array();
for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($explode_values); $i++) {
    $a[$explode_values[$i]] = $explode_values[$i];
}
var_dump($a);
var_dump($explode_values);
?>
{!! Form::select($checkpoint['id'].'_c[]', isset($error_messages[$checkpoint['id']]) ?$error_messages[$checkpoint['id']] : (count($explode_values) > 0 ? $a : array()),'' , array('multiple'=>'multiple', 'class'=>'form-control js-example-tags select2','id'=>$checkpoint['id'].'_c')) !!}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Consider adding more details which would help you to receive better answers

Comment: I have used  ternary operator ans isset condition

Comment: This is my code

Comment: isset($error_messages[$checkpoint['id']]) ?$error_messages[$checkpoint['id']] : (count($explode_values) > 0 ? $a : array() )

Comment: I am using multi select drop down. when I edit the page selected  values displayed and also empty value also display . i used var_dump(explode_values) i got the result for array (size=1)
  0 => string '' (length=0)

Comment: so this one consider array size 1 display empty value,

Comment: here my question is how to remove if null values for array

Comment: @sivakumar.s Learn how we roll, [13 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4944012/sivakumar-s?tab=questions) and *not even 1* marked as answer. Did you even upvote any of them?

Comment: Sorry my communication very worst that is the reson sir , Sorry